# descomprimir un fichero zlib

Tags: zip, gitlab

Estoy haciendo un proceso de limpieza de versiones antiguas de artefactos en GIT (a sabiendas que esto puede hacer que GIT de ciertos errores).

HE visto que GIT comprime esos ficheros en zlib.
Ruta por ejemplo de donde se almacenan:

> xpgit10.ldcb0001./usr/local/de/gitlab/repositorios/repositories/ECDY/REPOCARA.git/objects/9a>
>   ls -lrt total 20
>   -r--r--r-- 1 xpgit10 gpgitl1d 163 Dec 12 15:37 4d98cb0533fb7341399a7e7204159a1bd8bfd1

se ve que el formato del fichero es

> xpgit10.ldcb0001./usr/local/de/gitlab/repositorios/repositories/ECDY/REPOCARA.git/objects/9a>
>   4159a1bd8bfd1           < 4d98cb0533fb7341399a7e7204159a1bd8bfd1: VAX
>   COFF executable - version 24450

Estoy intentando hacer un proceso que descomprima ese fichero en otro directorio.
La idea es borrar/cambiar los ficheros que ya no necesite, y volver a comprimir con el mismo nombre.

Estoy intentando hacer esa descompresión pero no consigo hacerlo.
Lo mas parecido lo he visto con openssl, pero este solo muestra el contenido del fichero, pero no lo descomprime

> xpgit10.ldcb0001./tmp/unzip> openssl enc -z -none -d <
>   9e38a9490fc02219a44cfe1d5306ab49151665 commit 239tree
>   b225939232046a73af3d116e3700e21ef540fa87 parent
>   90b7f35d7bad3f1688d49be9037f65ebaf3b7338 author xe07904
>    1514548147 +0100 committer xe07904
>    1514548147 +0100
>
> hola

He probado con la solución que viene en git pero tampoco me funciona
https://github.com/pfalcon/pyflate

En mi servidor tengo la siguiente librería instalada

zlib.x86_64                             1.2.3-29.el6              @dvd.repo

**¿Es posible crear un proceso que pueda extraer los ficheros de un zlib?**

Answer (score -1):

Muy buenas,

estoy intentando hacer descomprimir ficheros que se han comprimido con zlib en git.

Si ejecuto un file sobre el fichero que quiero descomprimir veo que

xpgit10.xxxxxxx./usr/local/de/gitlab/repositorios/repositories/ECDY/REPOCARA.git/objects/83> 8c9987bd86bbe <
a90ad3f9987a403be349ddd028c9987bd86bbe: **VAX COFF executable not stripped** - version 11592

He visto que había un **bug en Debían** y sucedía lo mismo:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=509942

Parece ser que el error está relacionado con que se pierde la cabecera del fichero, por lo que no se puede descomprimir.

He buscado algo de información sobre RedHat y me he encontrado esto (es el SO en el que me estpy moviendo)

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1306910

¿Creéis que puede ser un bug del SO?

HE creado el siguinte codigo en Python

import zipfile
try:
    import zlib
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("example.zip", mode="w")

try:
    zf.write("test.txt", compress_type=compression)
finally:
    zf.close()

Como output se me genera un fichero comprimido en zlib llamado "example.zlib"

sin embargo este parece que si es correcto
xpgit10.ldcb0001./tmp> file example.zip
example.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

Comment: Hola. Para añadir info a la pregunta, edita la pregunta. Aquí sólo van los intentos de respuesta. Por favor, lleva esta info a tu pregunta y elimina la respuesta.